# How to do a two dimensional margin distribution?

Tags: r, distribution, sample, normal-distribution, multivariate-testing

I am ask to sample and then do a marginal distribution $f(x_1,x_5)$ and plot it. I have the following code which works but dnorm is used for one dimension so I was wondering if i need to change it to dmvnorm.

If so, i change mu=mu.marginal, sigma=sigma.marginal, added a y sample, but dmvnorm says error because of non array input. Anye help is appreciated.

Model of multivariable normal:

```
mu = c(1,2,6,2,-4)
sigma = c(1,2,1,0.5,2)
rho = diag(rep(1,5))
rho[1,2] = rho[2,1] = 0.4
rho[1,3] = rho[3,1] = -0.3
rho[1,4] = rho[4,1] = -0.7
rho[3,5] = rho[5,3] = 0.2
rho[4,5] = rho[5,4] = 0.5
Sigma = rho * (sigma %o% sigma)
```

my code:

```
p = c(1,5)
(mu.marginal = mu[p])
(Sigma.marginal = Sigma[p,p])
# p is one-dimensional: use dnorm() to compute marginal pdf
x = seq(-1,6,by=0.01)

fx = dnorm(x,mean=mu.marginal,sd=sqrt(Sigma.marginal))
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=x,y=fx),mapping=aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line(col="blue")
```

Comment: Your code comment says "p is one-dimensional", but `(x_1, x_5)` is two-dimensional... To make sure I understand properly your task, you are to sample from the marginal distribution of `(x_1, x_5)` and plot the samples?

Comment: yes sorry its meant to be p is two dimensional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you were on the right track with `mvtnorm` and came close to a solution... I'm not sure how you ran into a non-array input error, but here's what I got with using `mvtnorm`:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(1e4, mean = mu.marginal, sigma = Sigma.marginal)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) +
    geom_bin2d()
```

[image]

You can see it's fairly spherical, which is what you'd expect since the off-diagonal elements of `Sigma.marginal` are 0 (which means that `x_1` and `x_5` are marginally *independently* normally distributed...)

Comment: thank you, what would cause array errors usually in this case? ill try to replicate the code that yielded my error if i can

Comment: i used dmvnorm instead of mvtnorm::rmvnorm is there a reason why it might have happend?

Comment: @Isabelle Yes, perhaps; it depends on how specifically you called it (i.e. what arguments you gave. Without seeing the code you used to call `dmvnorm()`, my best guess would be that you passed something that was not a matrix as `sigma`